# How to get value of param thats declared a few times

Tags: php, mongodb

I'm building a PHP querying a mongodo database. I need to retreive the value of a param from the url, and there is potentially more than one.

An example url would look like this

http://localhost/api/v1/report-01?type=EE&type=ER

How would I retrieve the two values from `type`.

At the moment I'm only get one, and it's the last one.

```
  if (isset($params["TYPE"]) && in_array($params["TYPE"], ["EE", "ER"])) {
      $matchPipeline["TYPE"] = $params["TYPE"];
      echo "Printing Variables";
      echo $params["TYPE"];
    }
```

The code is only printing `ER`.

**I have no access to the frontend, only the backend so I can't change the URL structure**

Answer (score 0):

> How would I retrieve the two values from type.

With [ ] after your key

api/v1/report-01?type[]=EE&type[]=ER

Comment: I can't modify the URL structure.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by accessing directly to global [$_SERVER](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) variable and using [preg_match_all](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php), here is an example:

```
<?php

preg_match_all('/type=(\w+)/', $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'], $matches);
var_dump($matches[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just create this function query to array and split the value

```
function queryToArray($q)
{
   $arr = [];
   foreach(explode("&", $q) as $l)
   {
      $b = explode('=', $l);
      if ( (is_array($b) && count($b) > 0) )
        $arr[$b[0]] = $b[1];
   }
   return $arr;
}
$arr = parse_url($url_string);

print_r(queryToArray($arr['query']);
```